# How to find out what is causing DokuWiki to be unable to save after edit?

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, debug, dokuwiki

This is happening only with one single page, even when only adding/removing a single character. All other pages can be edited & saved.

localhost is Apache on Windows, if that matters.

How can I debug it? Can I turn on debugging in DokuWiki? Does it leave a log file? Maybe I need to update DokuWiki?

[image]

---

[Update] I upgraded DokuWiki, but the problem persists.